# How do I compare lines from python to csv?

Tags: python, file, csv

i'm trying to create a program that allows a user login using an existing csv file that contains the listed information. How do I get the program to read through the file to locate the username and password stored inside? Below is the code I am trying to run:

```
   login = input("To sign in type 1. To register a new account type 2: ")
if login == "1":
    log_username = True
    while log_username == True:
        user = input("Username: ")
        user_password = input("Password: ")
        saved_users = open(user+".csv","r")
        for line1 in saved_users:
            line1.split(",")
            for line2 in saved_users:
                line2.split(",")
                if user == saved_users:
                    if user_password == saved_users:
                            print("Login successful...")
                    else:
                        print("Incorrect password")
                        log_username == False
                else:
                    print("Incorrect username, please try again.")
                    log_username == False
```

[Example of csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDoss.png)

Comment: You should use the csv module instead of trying to split it up yourself.

Comment: And can you show an example of the setup of the csv file you are using?

Comment: @gommb ive attached the example in the above question now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you then (note that this implies there are no repeated usernames):

```
import csv
import re

user = input("Username: ")
user_password = input("Password: ")

with open('test.csv', 'r') as saved_users:
    reader = csv.reader(saved_users)
    for line in list(reader)[1:]: # I start at 1 to skip the column labels
        line = [re.sub('[\[\]\']', '', item) for item in line] # This cleans up the brackets and quotes from the csv file
        if line[0] == user and line[1] == user_password:
            print("Login successful...")
            break
    else:
        print("Incorrect password")
```